# My unrealengine lags when placing actors for world generation

Tags: unreal-engine4, voxel, unreal-blueprint

I want to make world generation sort of like minecraft with destructable environment, but even one layer of blocks makes my game lag a lot, so i would like to know if there is anyway i can reduce or prevent the lag. Or any alternative ways to creating world gen that doesn't lag that much. 
[image: My game]
My level blueprint that makes the world gen looks like this: 
[image: first half of code][image: second half of code]

(I couldn't fit it in one screenshot but the print string is the same in both pictures)
The cube actor which is spawning currently has no code but since i want a destrucable environment it will have code latter.

I have attepted to use voxel instead but it says im missing a .dll file, which im not sure what to do about. Where in the computer should i put that file?
The image here is in danish, but it says that the program could not be started, because VCRUNTIME140_1.dll is missing on the computer. Try to reinstall the program to fix the problem.

[image: voxel .dll file] [image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The game lags after you spawn or only while spawning the objects? consider using code instead of blueprints, usually you have better performances.

Answer (score 0):

Use hierarchical instanced static meshes instead actors! 
More details: [YouTube](http://hierarchical%20instanced%20stati)